# Filter values of Array<String> from another Array<String>

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have two arrays:

```
let arr1 = ["one.json", "two.json", "three.json"]
let arr2 = ["one.json", "three.json"]
```

Now I want to remove all values of `arr2` in `arr1`, so my expected result in the example above would be `let arrFiltered = ["two.json"]`. I know how to handle this using a for-loop, however, I thought there may is an easier and more performance-oriented solution?

Comment: for loop is the fastest solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `Set` instead of `Array` in this case.

```
let arr1 = Set(["one.json", "two.json", "three.json"])
let arr2 = Set(["one.json", "three.json"])

arr1.subtract(arr2)
```

**Fundamental Set Operations**

> The illustration below depicts two sets–a and b– with the results of
>   various set operations represented by the shaded regions.

[image]

- Use the intersect(_:) method to create a new set with only the values common to both sets.
- Use the exclusiveOr(_:) method to create a new set with values in either set, but not both.
- Use the union(_:) method to create a new set with all of the values in both sets.
- Use the subtract(_:) method to create a new set with values not in the specified set.

[Read more](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

Answer (score 5):

Solution using the `filter` function

```
let arr1 = ["one.json", "two.json", "three.json"]
let arr2 = ["one.json", "three.json"]

let arrFiltered = arr1.filter{ !arr2.contains($0) }
```

Comment: Strongly suggest this solution: everyone needs to learn filter anyway.